# why cron job stoped in new year 2021 in laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, cron-task

every thing works fine till 31 decemeber 2020 and in new year my cron job stoped working i dont know what happend i am using spatie laravel package to take db backup an i also have one other cron job in console and command
kernal.php

```
`<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\UpdateUserNotNew',
        
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $schedule->command('cron:update-user-not-new')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('backup:run')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('backup:clean')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}`
```

**my issue is resolved by**https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890784/14913109
only my php version was not integrated with php multimanager

Comment: Which versions did you used (PHP, Laravel, spatie/laravel-backup)?

Comment: php 7.2 laravel 5.5.50 and dont know about spatie i installed it in september 2020

Comment: Just a hint: Laravel 5 is EOL (end of life), so you should better upgrade to an officially supported version, f. ex. 6, 7 or 8.

Comment: This  can cause the problem, https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup#using-an-older-version-of-php--laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely not coming from `spatie/laravel-backup` package. To run Laravels cronjob you need to a have a central call in your crontab to [Laravels scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

```sh
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run
```

You can also check all the scheduled tasks locally by running

```sh
$ php artisan schedule:work
```

and if they run fine locally then there is an issue with your server, but not with Laravel.

Also always have a look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` if there are any errors showing up.

Comment: i seen my storage/logs/laravel.log goes to 135mb and my disk usage on cpanel is 100 persent o u think it cause an issue?

Comment: You should definitely debug all the error showing up in the log. Having that big error log does not mean anything good. Furthermore having a 100 percent disk usage is not a good sign as well. But this is surely out of scope of this question here.

Comment: it has old error history since the project is started now first i will clear log