# Syntax error near unexpected token `newline' in cPanel

Tags: linux, cron, backup, cpanel

I am trying to back up my database in Laravel using Spatie package. Every thing worked fine till 31 Decemeber 2020 and in New Year my cron job stoped working. I don't know what happened, but on my cPanel mail I am receiving this email:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 0: `/usr/local/bin/php /home2/scoopscr/public_html/artisan backup:run 1>> '
```

and this is the cron job I am applying:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home2/scoopscr/public_html/artisan backup:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Editing in a windows or Mac  environment?

Comment: linux cpenal server

Comment: Where/how did you create the script?

Comment: plz dont mind if i dont unerstand your meaning i think u have no experience about cpanel i have a website which is host by godaday server and this server is installed linux operating system on there server and i only write this comman on there server /usr/local/bin/php /home2/scoopscr/public_html/artisan backup:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 to take database backup

Comment: And I'm asking you "How did you write it" ...

Comment: when u perchase hosting services then servise provider provides you facility to write commands on your server in cron jobs we can only register commands there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227792/discussion-between-hamza-qureshi-and-tink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible solutions

1. check your php version and php multimanager in cpanel both match or not
2. go to storage/log/laravel log read cron error
3. in any controller use

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan; Artisan::call('backup:run'); dd(Artisan::output());`
now you can check your command working or not and able to find errors